# React doesn't load local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

First of all, project was setup without using `npx create-react-app`, all Webpack configuration was set manually.

React can show imported images or images from web.
But cannot load images like this `<img src="images/img1.jpg" />` or `<img src={require("./images/img1.jpg")} />` both don't work.

Maybe the real issue is something about paths?! I'm getting
[this error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLDBE.png).
But the paths should be fine. [My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qu7I.png)

Images don't load neither when using `npm run start` or `npm run build`.
My NPM scripts:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.config.js",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
      }
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                        outputPath: "imgs"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html"})
    ]
}
```

Comment: your outputPath in webpack config states 'imgs' and in the code you specify path `images`

Comment: If you navigate with your browser directly to `localhost:8080/images/img1.jpg` do you see the image?

Comment: @gbalduzzi he will need tho have the image inside the public folder to do that

Comment: @gbalduzzi No. I get `Cannot GET /images/img1.jpg`

Comment: @mtx If I try change to `src={require("./imgs/img1.jpg")}` I get compilation error: 
`ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './imgs/img1.jpg' in '/home/juris/Documents/My Projects/playground/webpack-images/src'` 
and if I do that in `src=imgs/img1.jpg` I don't get compilation error, but image still not shown.
I tried ./imgs/, /imgs/, imgs/ neither works.

Comment: @jsjuris1989 [check docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) you probably miss `publicPath` in your config. Try `publicPath: '/'`